# AttributeError 'module' object has no attribute 'decodebytes'

Tags: python, python-2.7, base64

I'm doing some processing on an image using `OpenCV`. Now I need to convert the base64 string to bytes. In `Python-3.6` I could use `base64.decodebytes` but I can't find the alternate module in `Python-2.7` . Is there any other alternative present in `Python-2.7` ?

```
cvimg = cv2.imdecode(np_img_array, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
tmp_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img = base64.b64encode(cv2.imencode('.jpg', tmp_img)[1])
img = base64.decodebytes(img)
```

NOTE: I'm using `Python-2.7` as one of the module I'm using has not been converted to `Python-3.6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 2 still has the base64 module built in. 
Using

```py
base64.standard_b64encode(s)
#and
base64.standard_b64decode(s)
#Where 's' is an encoded string
```

Should still work.